# Problem with Nvidia drivers for K20, C2070 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu, cuda

My Desktop has the following configuration,

- Processor: Intel Core I7-4770K 3.5 GHz
- Mother board: MSI Z87-G43 64GB DDR3 Intel Motherboard
- GPUs: NVIDIA Tesla K20, NVIDIA Tesla C2070
- and with 32 GB RAM.

I plan to use it for GPGPU based scientific computation in my research. And for that I want CUDA-5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I went for dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. Installation of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 went fine. Then I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338907/how-to-install-cuda-5-5-under-ubuntu-12-04-lts-64-bit) to install CUDA-5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04, but could not go beyond the installation of the Nvidia drivers (Step I).

After installing the proprietary Nvidia driver (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.20) suggested by Nvidia for K20 & C2070 and rebooting, the display freezes at the screen with the Ubuntu logo, before the login screen appears.

I've also tried with removing the proprietary Nvidia drivers and installing ppa based drivers, but that too doesn't work. Also as I would be needing CUDA, so I have to use proprietary Nvidia drivers.

How can I fix this issue ?

I would appreciate any help with fixing this problem.

Edit: To add, after attaching the GPUs to the mother board, the mother board expects the display to be taken from the discrete GPUs instead of the integrated graphics card on the mother board. So, currently the display is being taken from the C2070 card.

Solved: My problem is resolved. I just followed the instructions given for installation of CUDA-5.5 on Nvidia's website [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#package-manager-installation). Earlier I had tried to install the .run files for the drivers which didn't work. But using the .deb cuda-5.5 installer for Ubuntu 12.04 directly, which also includes the drivers, worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with xorg-edgers fresh X crack" PPA: this is the fresher drivers you can find for Ubuntu, for all recent graphic cards. They have versions for 12.04. And I personally use that on two workstations in production.

You can find all the information following the link below:

https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa