# How to boot to terminal (ubuntu 12.04/gtx660Ti)?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, cuda

trying to install CUDA for my ubuntu 12.04LTS. Installed the NVIDIA drivers for GTX660Ti but haven't yet run the updates. The manual for CUDA says I should now move to a tty via Ctrl+Alt+F1 but that brings a black screen, and the monitor goes to sleep showing nothing. Ctrl+Alt+F7 brings me back though. 
Thought I could instead modify the /etc/default/grub, uncommenting either one of these lines:
-GRUB_TERMINAL=console
-GRUB_GFXMODE=640X480
and then sudo update-grub.
Both end me into a Error: No video mode activated, which will not leave, and I cannot access anything until I crash it so that I can go to recovery.

So mainly I would like to just install the CUDA, but if I could get my Ctrl+Alt+F1 to work I would like that too. I have tried several ways to fix it, and they all just make things worse. What should I do?

What I'm following btw:
[How to install cuda 5.5 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338907/how-to-install-cuda-5-5-under-ubuntu-12-04-lts-64-bit)

Comment: You may be able to install proprietary drivers from booting to a root shell: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell

Comment: Alvar: that's the exact post I am trying to follow, and with which I have problems. I've linked it just there at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Thanks Takkat, at least I got into the non-graphic mode. Unfortunately runlevel didn't work (couldn't find /var/run/utmp), which was needed by the cuda-installer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the overall issue, but to boot into terminal if CTRL+ALT +F1 does not work, you could try this:

Open Terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

look for this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"
```

then update your grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

then restart:

```
sudo reboot now
```

if you want to use the desktop just type:

```
startx
```

Try at your own risk... backup ALL of your system first... :)

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. It ends up in the "Error: no video mode activated" -error, which doesn't let me do anything else.